# How to get properties with "Interface Segregation Principle" without casting in ViewModel

Tags: c#, interface, casting

According to "Interface Segregation Principle" I have

```
interface IMessage
{
   void Send();
   string ToAddress { get; set; }
   string FromAddress { get; set; }
}

interface ITextMessage : IMessage
{
   string Text { get; set; }
}

interface IEmailMessage : ITextMessage
{
   string Subject { get; set; }
}


class EmailMessage : IEmailMessage
{
   public string Text { get; set; }
   public string Subject { get; set; }
   public string FromAddress { get; set; }
   public string ToAddress { get; set; }

   public EmailMessage(string text, string subject /*more parameters*/)
   {
    Text = text; 
    Subject = subject;
    //other parameters
   }

   public void Send()
   {
     Console.WriteLine("Send Email : {0}", Text);
   }
}

class SmsMessage : ITextMessage
{
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public string FromAddress { get; set; }
  public string ToAddress { get; set; }

  public SmsMessage(string text /*more parameters*/)
  {
    Text = text; 
    //other parameters
  }

  public void Send()
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Send Sms : {0}", Text);
  }
}
```

Now I have simple example:

```
List<IMessage> Messages = new List<IMessage>(){new SmsMessage("SomeText"), 
EmailMessage("Hi!", "To Brad Pitt")};
```

How to get "Subject" property (for example) in Messages[1] item without casting item to EmailMessage? Which pattern should I use?

Comment: What are you going to do with the `subject` property? And what will happen if a `IMessage` has no `subject` property?

Comment: I think this does not have anything to do with patterns. you should use (Messages[1] as IEmailMessage)?.Subject

Comment: You cannot do that without casting.

Comment: IMessage - it's entity. I want provide this entity to simple Datagrid in WPF, and I want to know how to create a ViewModel for this. For that, I should get all properties in all interface implementations. But, I want to know: is it possible without castig?

Comment: Well, you should find a workaround for this. one would be to override tostring. AFAIK, you cannot do that in any easier way than casting.

Comment: "any easier way than casting" - I don't need "easier" way))) that's I ask this question in this forum.

Comment: Well if you want any way than casting, go for reflection. \

Comment: That's even worse.

Comment: No one said it is better.

Answer (score 0):

It's a polymorphism question.

Either put the `Subject` on the `IMessage` and return `null` when there is none (you could also provide a `HasSubject` property), otherwise you need to cast.

There is no right or wrong. If you don't want IMessage to know about Subjects, you do not want to have such a property there. If there are lots of different subinterfaces and subtypes, casting is probably better.

Comment: Well you can have a base abstract class and override properties/methods on any derived class. return types could be abstract, too. In this case you are free to add/ change any property you want (With attention to LSP)